# Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'google-auth-library'

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I have downloaded a full project that has been in use for about a year now, I got a new computer and am trying to upload a change to a function. I had errors and now I am trying to redeploy a function that I know works and is the same as the source in Google Cloud.

I run:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:generateThumbnail
```

and this is the output:

```
  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './dnssec'

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

I run npm install:

```
npm WARN functions@ requires a peer of eslint@2.x but none is installed.         You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN firebase-functions@0.8.2 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

audited 7867 packages in 6.019s
found 20 vulnerabilities (3 low, 17 moderate)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

then I ran `npm audit fix`:

```
npm WARN functions@ requires a peer of eslint@2.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN firebase-functions@0.8.2 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~5.10.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

removed 1 package and updated 5 packages in 7.583s
fixed 8 of 20 vulnerabilities in 7867 scanned packages
  2 package updates for 12 vulns involved breaking changes
  (use `npm audit fix --force` to install breaking changes; or do it by hand)
```

..I am still getting the same error as before:

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './dnssec'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I think this is an issue with npm not updating the packages correctly. I was running into the same error.

```
Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './dnssec'
```

I found that the dnssec resource is within the 'sshpk' node module folder. So in order **to correct the error** I just went into the node_modules folder of my functions directory and **removed the 'sshpk' module**, and while still in the functions directory **ran 'npm install'**. Hopefully this works for you and some other people running into this issue.

Cheers. Good luck!